# Is "I'm just doing things that everyone needs to do" a correct sentence?

Tags: optional-that

Is "I'm just doing things that everyone needs to do" a correct sentence?

*form 1.* The things you need to do.

*form 2.* The things **that** you need to do.

*form 1.* I'm just doing things everyone needs to do.

*form 2.* I'm just doing things **that** everyone needs to do.

From the two forms of sentence above, which is the correct one? The one with "that" or the one without? Or both?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell without context. It looks a little strange. Are you saying "I am just doing all the things that everyone else should be doing"?

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are okay.

"That" is optional when the phrase is necessary.  With a phrase that is not necessary, use "which."

"Please buy the gift (that) I like."

"The gift, which I like, is red."